# Making a string of usergiven_character*usergiven_repeatsinthestring(number of repeats)

Tags: c, pointers, memory

I think that the problem is with allocating the memory for the string, but probably there is more to it

What i have to do is get a character and a number from the user

And print a string that has the character appear in it number times

Like i give character: $ and number: 8

I need to make a string :$$$$$$$$

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    char *string;

    //Space for number
    ptr = (int *) calloc(1,sizeof(int));

    //Get number
    printf("Give any number: \n");
    scanf("%i",ptr);

    fflush(stdin);

    //Space for string(+1 for \0)
    string = (char *) calloc(*ptr+1,sizeof(char));

    //Get string
    printf("Give any character: \n");
    gets(string);

    //They dont give the *ptr+1 memory that i give to string
    printf("Size of string is: %i\n",sizeof(string));
    printf("Size of string is: %i\n",strlen(string));

    //I put the character *ptr times in the string
    for ( char *x = string; x-string<*ptr; x++)
        strcpy(x,string);

    //I print it
    printf("String is: ");
    puts(string);

    free(string);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

This works-----------------------------------------------------------------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int *ptr;
    char *string,*x,*c;

    //Space for number
    ptr = (int *) calloc(1,sizeof(int));

    //Get number
    printf("Give any number: \n");
    scanf("%i",ptr);

    //Space for string(+1 for \0)
    string = (char *) calloc(*ptr+1,sizeof(char));

    //Get string
    printf("Give any character: \n");
    scanf(" %c",string);

    //This was the problem
    c = (char *) calloc(1,sizeof(char));
    *c = *string;

    //I put the character *ptr times in the string
    for ( x = string; x-string<*ptr; x++)
        strcpy(x,c);

    //Just checking
    printf("Size of string is: %i\n\n",strlen(string));

    //I print it
    printf("String is: %s\n\n",string);

    free(string);
    free(ptr);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `fflush(stdin);` - don't do this. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: Note that `gets` has been deprecated and removed.

Comment: `sizeof(string)` will return the size of pointer.

Comment: the `strcpy` loop is a mystery for me.

Comment: @EugeneSh.     Ye i wasnt sure so i used both but none showed the memory that i wanted allocated

Comment: It will show the size of the pointer and the length of the string (which will be 1 in case of single character).

Comment: @EugeneSh.      The loop gets the address of string to x ,x-string =0 so with x++ the   loop will run *ptr times

Comment: @EugeneSh.     Ye i get 1 with strlen but i did allocate the memory for string so why i still get 1 ?

Comment: Because `strlen` doesn't care how much you have allocated. It is returning the length until the `\0` terminator.

Comment: @EugeneSh.     then i did allocate the memory,shouldnt the loop then copy the character to every empty slot ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggest at a minimum the following changes/suggestions:  (read comments as well.)

```
//Space for number
// ptr = (int *) calloc(1,sizeof(int));
//       ^^^^^^^
ptr = calloc(1,sizeof(int)); //No need to cast return of calloc in C.

// However,   
int val = 0; 
// would be a better choice of creating space for an integer.  
// (unless this is an assignment.)

//Get number
printf("Give any number: \n");
scanf("%i",ptr);
// or, if using val
scanf("%i", &val); //needs the address of operator for non pointer variable

//fflush(stdin);  // undefined behavior to do this

//Space for string(+1 for \0)
//string = (char *) calloc(*ptr+1,sizeof(char));
char string[12] = {0}; //simplify, define a char array and use it instead
                       //note the largest likely length of an integer is
                       //represented in a string is 11: "-2147483648"
                       // plus the nul character, thus string size is 12.
char c = 0;

//Get string - not really getting a string from user, but a char.
//get char (more accurate description on what you are actually doing
printf("Give any character: \n");
//gets(string);
// place user input into a string
scanf(" %c"m &c);  //note the space in front of %c.  It consumes newline character.
```

If you have a character and a number, say variables `c` and `ptr`, then the sprintf statement becomes:

```
sprintf(string, "%c%d", c, ptr);
```

Given `c == $` and `ptr == 5`, the loop to produce `$$$$$` could be:

```
memset(string, 0, strlen(string)+1);
for(int i = 0; i<ptr; i++)
{
    string[i] = c;
}
strcat(string[i] = 0; // terminate with nul character
```

`string` is now ready to print by any of these methods:
`printf(string);` or
`printf("%s", string);` or
`fputs(string, stdout);` or
`puts(string);`

Comment: Wait im checking this

Comment: Sorry i said "appear", but i need to make a string character % number 3 the string will be %%% and then i print it(example)

Comment: Hi ryyker thanks for trying to help me,really thanks.I didnt want to use memset or sprintf because we havent done those in class.I found the problem                                         
                                                                                                                              for ( char *x = string; x-string<*ptr; x++)
        strcpy(x,string);
                                                                                                                                            i was strcpy the character to X with string but string was the location

Comment: where i was adding the extra characters so i was copying the string to X while string was getting bigger and bigger,something like that :]

Comment: so this is instead of fflush(i googled fflush no one likes it,but our teacher told us to use it eh)                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                       
scanf(" %c"m &c);  //note the space in front of %c. It consumes newline character.

Comment: @Jesepy - `fflush()` has its appropriate uses.  But, if your instructor told you to use `fflush(stdin)`, then your instructor has made a mistake.  _`stdin` is a standard FILE* variable that points to the input stream normally used for keyboard input. The fflush() function is deemed to flush buffers. ... So, if the file stream is for input use, as stdin is, the behaviour is undefined, therefore it is not acceptable to use fflush() for clearing keyboard input._  ( _Google_ "is fflush(stdin) undefined". )